# Stumped: PHP's fopen is failing on hex characters in 5.3.1/WIN

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character, fopen

I'm having an unexpected problem with php in my attempt to decode iTunes URLs into filesystem names. Itunes gives me the following location for a filename  crafted to test UTF8 compatibility.

file://localhost/C:/Users/user/Desktop/%E6%9D%BF%C3%AD%E9%87%8E%E5%8F%8B%E7%BE%8E%D0%B8%C3%B0%D0%B9%C3%BC%C3%B6+%CF%88%E6%BC%A2%E8%AA%9E%E7%AE%80%D8%B1%D7%91%D6%B5%D6%BC%D7%99%D8%A8%D9%8A.mp3

original filename is a mix of alphabets and chars: 板í野友美иðйüö+ψ漢語简رבֵּיبي.mp3

I have converted that to php's string format and stripped the file://loaclhost/ prefix:
$filename = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/\xE6\x9D\xBF\xC3\xAD\xE9\x87\x8E\xE5\x8F\x8B\xE7\xBE\x8E\xD0\xB8\xC3\xB0\xD0\xB9\xC3\xBC\xC3\xB6+\xCF\x88\xE6\xBC\xA2\xE8\xAA\x9E\xE7\xAE\x80\xD8\xB1\xD7\x91\xD6\xB5\xD6\xBC\xD7\x99\xD8\xA8\xD9\x8A.mp3"

when I attempt to fopen( $filename, 'r' ); windows complains that the file doesn't exist.

This is on PHP5.3.1 (XAMPP) on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

`+`, unless escaped, means space in the URL. Windows is therefore properly stating that the file doesn't exist since it contains a space, not a `+`.

Instead of attempting to decode the URL yourself, why not use the established [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/urldecode) provided by PHP?

```
$iTunesURI = 'file://localhost/C:/Users/user/Desktop/%E6%9D%BF%C3%AD%E9%87%8E%E5%8F%8B%E7%BE%8E%D0%B8%C3%B0%D0%B9%C3%BC%C3%B6+%CF%88%E6%BC%A2%E8%AA%9E%E7%AE%80%D8%B1%D7%91%D6%B5%D6%BC%D7%99%D8%A8%D9%8A.mp3';
$iTunesPath = ltrim(parse_url($iTunesURI, PHP_URL_PATH), '/');

$filename = urldecode($iTunesPath);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the other approach to cleaning up the iTunes urls. Unfortunately, this isn't the problem.. I've already tried replacing the "+" with hex chars and tried urldecode and rawurldecode, but I haven't found any way to get a seemingly legit filename to read with the longer byte lengths. I have a feeling that php may not be compiled right in this edition of XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Windows box with PHP on it right now to test, but I think your problem is likely that the [filename encoding in Windows is normally UTF-16](http://www.rooftopsolutions.nl/blog/filesystem-encoding-and-php).  Undex Linux, using an ext3 filesystem, I created the filename you indicated, then wrote the following PHP file (encoded in UTF-8):

```
<?php
$filename = "板í野友美иðйüö+ψ漢語简رבֵּיبي.mp3";
$fh = fopen($filename, 'r');
$contents = fread($fh, filesize($filename));
print $contents;
var_dump($filename);
fclose($fh);

function encode_filename($fname) {

    $replaced_filename =
        preg_replace_callback(
            '/[^\x20-\x7F]/',
            create_function(
                '$matches',
                'return "\x" . dechex(ord($matches[0]));'
            ),
            $fname
        );
    return $replaced_filename;

}

print "Encoded UTF-8 filename: " . encode_filename($filename) . "\n";

$filename = mb_convert_encoding($filename, "UTF-8", "UTF-16");
print "Encoded UTF-16 filename: " . encode_filename($filename) . "\n";

?>
```

It successfully read my target file and outputted its contents.

The output for the encoded filenames was:

```
Encoded UTF-8 filename: \xe6\x9d\xbf\xc3\xad\xe9\x87\x8e\xe5\x8f\x8b\xe7\xbe\x8e\xd0\xb8\xc3\xb0\xd0\xb9\xc3\xbc\xc3\xb6+\xcf\x88\xe6\xbc\xa2\xe8\xaa\x9e\xe7\xae\x80\xd8\xb1\xd7\x91\xd6\xb5\xd6\xbc\xd7\x99\xd8\xa8\xd9\x8a.mp3
Encoded UTF-16 filename: \xee\x9a\x9d\xeb\xbf\x83\xea\xb7\xa9\xe8\x9e\x8e\xee\x96\x8f\xe8\xaf\xa7\xeb\xba\x8e\xed\x82\xb8\xec\x8e\xb0\xed\x82\xb9\xec\x8e\xbc\xec\x8e\xb6\xe2\xaf\x8f\xe8\xa3\xa6\xeb\xb2\xa2\xee\xa2\xaa\xe9\xbb\xa7\xea\xba\x80\xed\x9e\x91\xed\x9a\xb5\xed\x9a\xbc\xed\x9e\x99\xe2\xb9\xad\xe7\x80\xb3
```

This matches your UTF-8 encoding, so that seems right.  Try the UTF-16 encoding.  Or, do like I did, and embed the filename directly in the file and encode the file in UTF-16.

Comment: Thanks for all the background. while upsampling to UTF16 didn't do the trick, I think the article you posted may be on to something with php being compiled wrong for the newer windows FS APIs, this unit test is green on OSX and ubuntu, so I think something is amiss in the filesystem communication once you get into multibyte unicode.